# Greenshot failed to Start

Tags: greenshot

Since 2 days ago, my Greenshot won't start anymore. I tried older versions, too.

Can somebody give advice?

```
Software version: 1.2.10.6-RELEASE-c2414cf0149a1475ea00520effc01b40087c225c (64 bit)
.NET runtime version: 4.0.30319.34014+
Time: 2017-11-29 08:17:56 +01:00
OS: unknown   (x64)  6.3 build 9600 revision 0
GDI object count: 23
User object count: 16

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.

Stack:
   bei System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   bei GreenshotPlugin.Controls.HotkeyControl.HotkeyFromString(String hotkey)
   bei Greenshot.MainForm.RegisterHotkey(StringBuilder failedKeys, String functionName, String hotkeyString, HotKeyHandler handler)
   bei Greenshot.MainForm.RegisterWrapper(StringBuilder failedKeys, String functionName, String configurationKey, HotKeyHandler handler, Boolean ignoreFailedRegistration)
   bei Greenshot.MainForm.RegisterHotkeys(Boolean ignoreFailedRegistration)
   bei Greenshot.MainForm..ctor(CopyDataTransport dataTransport)
   bei Greenshot.MainForm.Start(String[] arguments)

Configuration dump:
```

Comment: Try reinstalling the .Net framework

Comment: I've posted you an answer. Feel free to mark it as solved so others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already reinstalled Greenshot and it didn't work, try reinstalling the .Net framework.

The error you are posting (although I don't understand german) I do recognize a .Net error, so it could be very simply be that.